# Local Dask worker unable to connect to local scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

While running Dask 0.16.0 on OSX 10.12.6 I'm unable to connect a local `dask-worker` to a local `dask-scheduler`. I simply want to follow the official [Dask tutorial](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/blob/master/04_distributed.ipynb). Steps to reproduce:

**Step 1:** run `dask-scheduler`

[image]

**Step 2:** Run `dask-worker 10.160.39.103:8786`

[image]

The problem seems to related to the dask scheduler and not the worker, as I'm not even able to access the port by other means (e.g., `nc -zv 10.160.39.103 8786`).

[image]

However, the process is clearly still running on the machine:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess is that due to network rules your computer may not accept network connections that look like they're coming from the outside world.  You might want to try using `dask-worker localhost:8786` and see if that works instead.

Also, as a reminder, you can always start a scheduler and worker directly from Python without creating dask-scheduler and dask-worker processes

```
from dask.distributed import Client
# client = Client('scheduler-address:8786')
client = Client()  # create scheduler and worker automatically
```

As a foolproof method you can also pass `processes=False` which will avoid networking issues entirely

```
client = Client(processes=False)
```