# Dask Event loop was unresponsive - work not parallelized

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

This is a follow-up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067066/local-dask-worker-unable-to-connect-to-local-scheduler/48067814#48067814). I'm now trying to run Dask on multiple EC2 nodes on AWS.

I'm able to start up the scheduler on the first machine:

[image]

I then start up workers on several other machines. From the other machines I'm able to access the scheduler using `nc -zv ${HOST} ${PORT}`, and the workers otherwise seem to be able to connect to the master, as evidenced by the worker's sysout: `Registered to: tcp://10.201.101.108:31001`, but almost immediately the worker complains about a timeout loop.

[image]

From the master node, in my Jupyter notebook I then connect to the scheduler:

`dask_client = Client('10.201.101.108:31001')`

But the work does not propagate to the worker nodes (worker-node CPU stays at <1%) or even to the worker running on the same machine as the scheduler. This is a highly parallelized task and when running on a single machine (i.e., using `Client(processes=False)` consumes every core on the machine).

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to see the "Event loop was unresponsive" wanring when first connecting, depending on your network.

Some things to check

1. `client.get_versions(check=True)`
2. Does `client.scheduler_info()['workers']` have anything?  If not then you might have some trouble connecting
3. Consider looking at the worker logs with `client.get_worker_logs()`
4. Try running a simple computation like `client.submit(lambda x: x + 1, 10).result()`

Comment: `client.get_versions(check=True)` shows all of the nodes and their software versions, but both `client.scheduler_info()['workers']` and `client.get_worker_logs()` hang indefinitely. That makes it seem like it's a network connectivity issue, but if true how would the scheduler have been able to return results from `client.get_versions(check=True)` if it were not able to connect to the worker nodes?

Comment: Actually, I take that back: `client.scheduler_info()['workers']` and `client.get_worker_logs()` aren't hanging. They're able to return results about all of the worker nodes quickly and without problems

Comment: I've now also tried on my personal Mac (work Mac might have been more locked down) and the issue persists.